# The output of tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell

Tags: tensorflow

What is the output of MultiRNNCell() looks like, and which is the output of last layer? output[-1] or output[0].

I've looked for the official document: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/MultiRNNCell

But I didn't see any further explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The output is the output of the last cell, not the concatenated outputs of all the cells.